# Why doesn't 480px image fit on 1280px android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, screen-resolution, landscape-portrait

I am using jquery mobile, but I am using standard `<img>` for the image. The image is 480x200.

I view the site on 1280x720 mobile phone:

- portrait ... the image does not fit,
- landscape ... fits

Why doesn't it fit in portrait viewing?

*I am not asking 'how to make it fit' ... sure, set it to 100% ... but that's not my question. thanks.*

Comment: I think, you should see this: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your phone is 360 x 640 **dp** (xhdpi) and 480 **px** image is assumed to work well on **mdpi** devices, so it is scaled 2x to work on **xhdpi**.